# How to I prompt a program to ask the user to give command line arguements multiple times?

Tags: c++

So I am tasked to create a program that allows the user to enter command line arguments in order to buy stocks. Basically the user passes 1 of 7 arguments to trigger a function. I want to make it so that after the program loops(one argument and corresponding function later), it will ask for another more command line arguments. Is that physically possible?
(First time asking questions, forgive me if I don't know a lot)

P.S. My professor won't allow me to use cin at any point of the program

Comment: If you're taking more input during the program, its not "command-line arguments" then. Please make your question more clear. The fact that you aren't allowed to use `cin` is very weird. Is a workaround like C input functions allowed?

Comment: Or does he expect you to save a temporary file attesting that `yourProgram -argument1` was called, so that `yourProgram -argument2` reads it and can proceed, and so on until `yourProgram -argument7`?

Comment: command line arguments is what the user passes on starting the application. That happens only once. While your program is running you can ask the user for input as often as you like

Comment: I think it's what m88 means, I just read again and he allows cin in functions but not in class. But medio's answer cleared my understanding, thx.